# HtmlUnit: Skip JS execution

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

**Problem:**

- I am parsing pages generated by JS using HtmlUnit.
- I have to wait until all JS are loaded and then parse page.
- All these pages share same JS scripts.
- There is a one problematic script that won't parse.
- The problematic script does not affect html rendering.

**What I want to do:**

- I want to detect name of the problematic script.
- Put this name on blacklist.
- And skip it for further parsing.

This is the code I use for JS loading...

```
  private void waitForJs(WebClient client, HtmlPage page) throws Exception {
    int maxDelay = 1000;
    int attempts = 10;
    int i = client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(maxDelay);
    while (i > 0 && attempts > 0) {
      i = client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(maxDelay);
      if (i == 0) {
        break;
      }
      synchronized (page) {
        page.wait(500);
      }
      log("Waiting for JS (" + i + "), attempts: " + attempts, false);
      attempts--;
    }
  }
```

I had to intoduce "attempts" variable in order to not stuck on loading of damaged script. Instead of this, I want to put all problematic script(s) - remaining in waitForJs - on blacklist and skip their loading in the futures. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The code above has an encoding issue - we have to use the correct charset when getting the bytes from the content string.

```
WebResponseData data = new WebResponseData(content.getBytes(response.getContentCharset()),
       response.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusMessage(), response.getResponseHeaders());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the content of the JavaScript to be empty string, as hinted [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#HowToModifyRequestOrResponse):

```
new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) {

        public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
            WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);
            if (request.getUrl().toExternalForm().contains("my_url")) {
                String content = response.getContentAsString();

                // change content
                content = "";

                WebResponseData data = new WebResponseData(content.getBytes(),
                        response.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusMessage(), response.getResponseHeaders());
                response = new WebResponse(data, request, response.getLoadTime());
            }
            return response;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how can I load all internal Javascripts using your code and after loading execute them for original page?